# C: need a "sign" type

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

For my C computation, I need a sign type (an associated operator is acceptable) that can do the following:

```
type sign_t = -1 | 0 | 1

integer mult_sign(integer i, sign_t s)
{
    switch (s) {
    case -1: return -i;
    case 0: return 0;
    case 1: return i;
    }
}
```

Clarification: The value of the sign is not known at compile time!

For now, I'm using C `signed`s with integer value of `-1`,`0`, `1`, respectively, and the operation is C multiplication `myint * mysign`. But I'm wondering if this has performance implications: for each mult-with-sign-operation, a hardware multiplication is employed which might be slower than negation | set to 0 | don't touch.

What would be the ideal way to do this in C?

What would be the ideal way if we take away the value 0 from the sign values (so only -1 and 1 are valid)?

Architecture specific hacks / standard nonconformness are very fine if you tell me where they are.

Comment: An integer multiplication is very likely to be faster than branching (which is what a `switch` block implies)...

Comment: From the fact that you did not mention branch prediction in your brief rambling about performance, I conclude that you shouldn't be worrying about performance at this level (i.e. micro optimization).

Comment: Certainly I wouldn't like to implement this with branching. As you see, this question is tagged bit-manipulation. And yes, I want to do micro-optimization. The program is http://spoj.com/problems/BULK, and already I have a good algorithm and one of the fastest programs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Multiplication seems like an awesome choice.

It's very clear and concise, and relies only on basic (well-understood) mathematical properties of integers.

You don't say much about your execution environment, but on typical desktop CPU:s integer multiply has been single-cycle for a long time. So it's hard to come up with something faster.

Also, doing a multiply removes the need to branch to "decide" what to do, which is often much (much) better than jumping around to do something "simpler".

Comment: Thanks, this is the thing I should have known: Multiplication is one cycle.

Comment: Just to nitpick a little. Multiply is not single cycle. It has a latency of between 3 and 7 (depending on operand size and CPU type) cycles. But as they are pipelined they can compute (theoretically) one multiplication every cycle if the operands are not dependent. In practice the out of order machinery of the CPU will hide this latency in most cases but in some cases not and being aware of that can be of help.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly not a performance bottleneck. Just use a plain int.

Incidentally, you do realize that taking the negative of int min will result in undefined behavior? Usually you'll just get the same thing back, but you probably want to defined `-fwrapv` or whatever it is to ensure this.

Comment: I didn't know. Does this apply to `-myint` only or also to `myint * s` where s isn't known at compile time to be `-1`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a small microcontroller without fast hardware multiplication then you should do it case-by-case. In this case also the overhead for a branch is small.

Otherwise just use the multiplication.